# How to undefine a variable in Scheme?

Tags: variables, scheme, undefined

How to undefine a variable in Scheme? Is this possible?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need that or what is your intention?

Comment: I'm newbie on Scheme or functional language.
I imagined environment as an hash-table, and I worried about some kind of memory management. I thought explicit un-definging required to release it's memory under GC. And now I'm some confusing. I'm trying to understand lower level behavior of Scheme.

Comment: Of course, it's obvious releasing of memory is not required on Scheme, but I want to know details.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What are you trying to achieve?  Can you post example code where this would be useful?

Comment: Oh guys, please stop feeling anger on my question. I just asked a question as a newbie, and now I know it was a stupid question :)
I thought in C way, but I realized it was not a good idea on Scheme.

Comment: There is no portable way. As the best effort, now you can `set!` the variable to `'()` since the empty list is guaranteed unique and not allocated again in R7RS.

Comment: Note this is not the C way, since the environments in C (usually the translation-time symbol tables living in the compiler for each translation unit during compilation) are really "purely functional"(TM): you have no chance to undeclare any identifiers (except the macro names) at all. This is even more strict than Scheme which can re`define` identifiers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scheme, variables are defined with either lambda, or one of the various lets. If you want one of them to be 'undefined' then all you need to do is leave the scope that they're in. Of course, that's not really undefining them, it's just that the variable is no longer bound to its previous definition.

If you're making top level definitions, using (define), then technically you're defining a function. Since Scheme is functional, functions never really go away. I suppose that technically, it's stored in some sort of environment function somewhere, so if you were intimately familiar with your implementation (and it's not safeguarded somehow) you could probably overwrite it with your own definition of the globabl environment. Barring that, I'd say that your best bet would be to redefine the function to return the null list- that's really as empty as you get.

Comment: you could also do (set! x (display 'ignored)) because `display` returns "an unspecified value".

Comment: You can define non-function values at the top level in Scheme, and locally bound functions do indeed "go away".

Comment: Thanks for answer. I realized my question was something wrong :) I realized 'define' defines something in top-level scope, so it just remained until scope ends (program exit)

Answer (score 10):

You're touching a nerve here.  Scheme doesn't have a very clear standard notion of how top-level environments work.  Why?  Because the Scheme standards represent a compromise between two sets of people with very different ideas of how Scheme should work:

- The interpretive crowd, who sees the top-level environment as you describe above: a runtime hash-table where bindings are progressively added as program interpretation proceeds.
- Then there's the compilation crowd, who sees the top-level environment as something that must be fully computable at compilation time (i.e., a compiler must be able to conclusively identify all of the names that will be bound in the top-level environment).

Your "how do I undefine a variable" question only makes sense in the first model.

Note that the interpretive model, where a program's top-level bindings depend on what code paths get taken, makes efficient compilation of Scheme code much harder for many reasons. For example, how can a Scheme compiler inline a procedure invocation if the name of the procedure is a top-level binding that may not just change during runtime, but even disappear into nothingness?

I'm firmly in the compilation camp here, so what I would recommend to you is to avoid writing code that relies on the ability to add or remove top-level bindings at runtime, or even that requires the use of top-level variables (though those are often unavoidable).  Some Scheme systems (e.g., Racket) are able to produce reasonably good compiled code, but if you make those assumptions you'll trip them up in that regard.

Comment: Oh nice explanation. Can I treat *interpretive vs compilation* as *dynamic vs static* (at top-level)?

Comment: Yeah, basically.  For efficient compilation, you want all top-level environments to be statically known.  This means knowing all of the bindings that exist at the top-level, and which of them are subject to mutation anywhere in the program.Any immutable top-level procedure bindings can then be compiled as direct function calls, and may be easily inlined; calls to top-level bindings that may be mutated must add an indirect lookup (because the binding may change at runtime), and may not be easily inlined.

Comment: While this truly reflects the thoughts of some Scheme users, it is not [technically true](http://fexpr.blogspot.com/2016/08/interpreted-programming-languages.html#sec-ict-chaos). More specifically here: there is no essential differences of difficulties on analyzing a program with probable re-`define`ing and undefining bindings (either top-level or not). Abuse of environment mutation _is_ bad, but this is equal on defining and undefining except those able to be rewritten without environment modifications (i.e. `let` family).

Answer (score 4):

Scheme ([R7RS](https://small.r7rs.org/)) has no standard compliant way to remove a top-level binding.

If you evaluate a non existing variable, you get an error:

```
(eval 'a)
; => ERROR: undefined variable: a
```

If you define it, the variable gets added to the top-level environment.

```
(define a 1)
(eval 'a)
; => 1
```

As from now no matter what you do, you will not get an error, if you access the variable.

If you set it to false, you will get false:

```
(set! a #f)
(eval 'a)
; => #f
```

Even if you set it to something unspecified, it is unlikely that you get an error:

```
(set! a (if #f #t))
(eval 'a)
; =>
```

**But** some Schemes may have a non-standard way to remove a top-level binding. MIT Scheme provides the function [`unbind-variable`](http://web.mit.edu/scheme/current/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Top_002dlevel-Environments.html#index-unbind_002dvariable-1975).

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the other answers there is no standard way of manipulating the namespace in Scheme. For a specific implementation there might be a solution.

In Racket the top-level variables are stored in a namespace. You can remove a variable using `namespace-undefined-variable`.

There is no way of removing a local variable.

[http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html?q=namespace#%28def.*%28%28quote.*~23~25kernel%29._namespace-undefine-variable%21%29%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html?q=namespace#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._namespace-undefine-variable%21%29%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
(set! no-longer-needed #f)
```

Does this achieve the effect you want?  You can also use define at the top level.

```
guile> (define nigel "lead guitar")
guile> nigel
"lead guitar"
guile> (define nigel #f)
guile> nigel
#f
guile>
```

You could then re-`define` the variable.  This all depends on the scope of the variables, of course: see [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487138/how-to-undefine-a-variable-in-scheme/3487975#3487975).

Comment: Just a note for Eonil: set! destroys referential transparency because it introduces side effects, and thus should be avoided if you want to stick to being purely functional.

Comment: Setting a variable to false it not the same as undefining it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unbind a variable in standard Scheme. You could set! the variable to 'undefined, I guess, or you could write a metainterpreter which reifies environments, allowing you to introduce your own notion of undefining variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if your point is to do the equivalent of "free" or de-allocate, then no you're pretty much out of luck. you can't de-allocate a variable. you *CAN* re-define it to something small, like #f, but once you've done (define foo 'bar) the variable foo will exist in some form until you end the program.

On the other hand, if you use let, or letrec, of course, the name only exists until the relevant close paren...

Comment: Thanks for answer. I realized it was just a scope problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is not stupid. In AutoLISP has unexisting (undefined) variable apriori supposted value "nil" (even if the variable does not exist in memory - it means - if it is not in a table of variables - then the value is "nil" - "false"). It means also false. And it is also empty list. If you program some kind of list processing function, it is enough to make initial test only by:

```
(if input-list ....)
```

When you want to explicitly undefine any variable, you may do this:

```
(setq old-var nil); or: (setq old-var ())
```

I like it. The keyword "setq" means "define". What is better on bounding and unbounding variables in other dialects? You must test if they exist, if they are lists, you need garbage-collector, you may not undefine variable to explicitly free memory. Following command can not be written if variable "my-list" is not defined:

```
(define my-list (cons 2 my-list))
```

So I think the AutoLISP way is for programming much better. Possibilities, that I written, you may use there. Unfortunately the AutoLISP works in some CAD engineering graphical systems only.

Comment: While the question is not necessarily stupid, the design in AutoLISP is controversial. The `nil` is like JavaScript's `undefined`, considered harmful popularly. It is also error-prone enough with the fact that all main LISP dialects nowadays do not use dynamic scoping by default, except AutoLISP and Emacs Lisp.

Comment: One more example: [Racket 6.1 changed `#<undefined>` to exception in the context for "providing early and improved feedback to developers about improper use of variables"](https://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/racket-61-released/?topicPageSponsorship=35c1a390-2c3e-4e28-8bc8-36be730dda61).