# Unbind variable function

Tags: scheme

I would like to define an unbind-var function that unbinds the closest binding of a variable.

For example

```
({let {[x 2]}
  {let {[x 3]}
     {let {[z 3]}
      {+ x {unbind-var x {+ x z}}}}}})
```

would return 3+2+3=8 (it uses the first value of x in the unbind-var form).
There can be arbitrary nestings.

It seems the only strategy is walk back from the unbind-var x until we find the second let for x. I.e. somehow I have to convert the entire expression into a list and then pick pieces with car/first and cdr/rest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to undefine a variable in Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487138/how-to-undefine-a-variable-in-scheme)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why don't you just use different names? I suspect there's an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: Extra parentheses around the expression will signal  "Apply: <number> is not a procedure". There is no way to do this in Scheme. It might be that some of th eimplementations have features that lets you modify/change the call stack, but it's not portable and **not Scheme standard**.  What are you trying to achieve with this? If you state the real problem you are having we might help you with that instead of this.

Comment: I am fiddling with Scheme  (among other functional languages) to build a mini compiler and thought this would be possible.

Comment: Not unless you are writing your own compiler for Scheme. Such a construct is not available in standard Scheme implementations.

Comment: @JennyToy In your own compiler you can since you know how you set up your frames and closures. In the simplest form your compiler resolves the symbols that are lexical at compile time and it would be easy to have the compiler ignore a frame and resolve to an earlier frame or even say to resolve it in the global scope if there are no more in the lexical scope when seeing that `unbind-var` special form. The important thing is that this does not rely features in scheme since you are adding features to your own compiler.