# Sandboxing Guile by deleting unwanted libraries?

Tags: lisp, sandbox, guile

I have an [open-source GUI](https://github.com/bcrowell/opengrade) for which I've just implemented a very basic extension mechanism that allows the user to embed a snippet of Lisp (Guile) code in a document to allow certain functions to be customized. Currently the use case (my own) is that in a certain situation I just want a certain number to be divided by 10 automatically.

In principle this means that if someone uses my GUI, someone else can send them a document containing a Trojan horse attack in the form of malicious Guile code. This seems unlikely in reality due to my very small user base and the relevant social factors, but anyway I would like to protect against this by sandboxing the code.

Guile 2.2.1 has a sandboxing mechanism: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Sandboxed-Evaluation.html However, this seems entirely focused on preventing excessive use of resources (and many users will not have such a current version of Guile, e.g., I don't right now).

Is it possible in a Guile program, after the interpreter has started up, to delete libraries such as [POSIX](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/POSIX.html#POSIX) so that any later code can't do things like read files? If so, then I could just have my GUI prepend the sandboxing code to the potentially untrusted code supplied by the document. My goal would basically be to ensure that the untrusted code would have to be 100% without side effects.

It seems like other people must have run into this issue before, since Guile has been promoted as a standard extension language for Linux.

EDIT: After coming across  [How to undefine a variable in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487138/how-to-undefine-a-variable-in-scheme) , it seems to me that I could probably create a new scope, override the definition of any dangerous function by doing a `set!` within that scope, and then execute the untrusted code within that scope. I suppose if I could read the entire symbol table somehow, I could do this kind of overriding on every function that isn't on a whitelist. This just seems clumsy and inefficient, and might depend on reading the symbol table using some implementation-specific mechanism. It also might be vulnerable to syntactical tricks, like if the untrusted code uses a ) to pop itself out of the scope of the sandbox.

Comment: You almost certainly want to do this by constructing modules to restrict the bindings the program can see to ones which are safe.  Additionally you need to deal with programs which eat too much time or space.  That appears to be exactly the combination of things the Guile sandbox facility gives you (note the stuff about 'pure bindings' which is the module stuff): unless for some reason you *can't* use a new enough version of Guile I'd strongly recommend using it.

Comment: @tfb: I see, thanks. I hadn't understood that that was what that part of the documentation was talking about at all. Maybe I need to find an example somewhere of how someone has used this.

Comment: @tfb: *unless for some reason you can't use a new enough version of Guile I'd strongly recommend using it* It looks like the sandbox module requires guile 2.2+. This makes it impractical for me to use it, since ubuntu is way behind on packaging, and I can't tell users that they have to compile guile from source in order to protect themselves from Trojan horse attacks. I've ended up deciding just not to use guile as my extension language, am using the calculator program bc instead. It's not a full-featured programming language, but it's better than nothing.